# Фильтрация строк при помощи функции MatchesMask

Tags: delphi, строки

Использую функцию `MatchesMask` для отсеивания ненужных строк.

Текст вот такого плана:

```
txt11.txt221.txt325.txt4:5787899 (тут без пробела в конце строки)
txt11.txt221.txt325.txt4:578799 (А тут есть пробел в конце строки)
txt11.txt221.txt325.txt4:57878 dsdsssdwddwdww
```

На выходе должно получиться  (то есть условие (после ":" и "цифр" - если появляются буквы то такую - строку отсеять):

```
txt11.txt221.txt325.txt4:5787899
txt11.txt221.txt325.txt4:578799
```

Использую вот такого плана - фильтр:*

```
if MatchesMask(s,'*.*.*.*[:]*') then
   writeln(f2, S);
```

Но ничего не выходит, просто копируются 3 строки. Может есть какой-либо фильтр под эту функцию, кто может подсказать?

Comment: Все строки подходят под маску. Сформулируйте, чем плоха третья.

Comment: @MBo, но мне просто нужно сделать так: Что если после  :578799 (то есть условие (после ":" и "цифр" - если появляются буквы то такую - строку отсеять).

Comment: Некоторые варианты можно отсечь `if MatchesMask(s,'*.*.*.*[:]*[0-9][!a-z]')`. А вообще язык MatchesMask примитивный, сложного результата не добиться, так что более универсально - регулярки или в данном случае - вариант zed-а

Comment: @MBo, Понятно, спасибо. Буду еще думать. На самом деле, я, уже много в чем, в регулярных выражениях, разобралась. Но они очень и очень медленные.

Comment: Но функция zed из прошлой ветки - быстрая.

Comment: @MBo, про функцию zed даже не спорю. Я в общем сказала. А его функция быстро работает.

Comment: дак вы и оставьте ту быструю функцию, только дополните ее новым условием. Пусть основная фильтрация осуществляется тем быстрым алгоритмом.